# D3 line generator only generating NaN values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to create a line generator function to which I can send arbitrary datasets for rendering. However im only getting NaN back from the function. Here is my demo code that shows the issue im having: [JsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/t6e7rsLd/4/). (Click the bug in the right corner and choose command line to see the console.log output if it is not shown automatically)

```
var dataset = [{"x": "W3", "y":1}, {"x": "W5", "y":12},{"x": "W8", "y":1}, {"x": "W11", "y":9}];

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 100 - 2]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([25 - 4, 0]);

x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.y; }));

var sparkLine = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x( function (d) { x(d.x); })
  .y( function (d) { y(d.y); });

console.log(sparkLine(dataset))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `return` in the definition of sparkLine's x and y.

Also in your fiddle I had to replace the douple square brackets around your data with single square brackets to make it a simple array instead of a nested array.

```
var dataset = [{"x": 3, "y":1}, {"x": 5, "y":12},{"x": 8, "y":1}, {"x": 11, "y":9}];

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 100 - 2]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([25 - 4, 0]);

x.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.y; }));

var sparkLine = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x( function (d) { return x(d.x); })
  .y( function (d) { return y(d.y); });

console.log(sparkLine(dataset));
```

Here is a fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/kke56vzc/